# How would you say something like "telling important information to others" with one word?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm not a native english speaker, and I don't know the exact phrase or word for the action of telling important information to others on a flyer/website/etc. I'd say announce but I think this is not the perfect word for it. E.g.: if I shout "wow, I've seen that xy is on discount at abc shop, check it out" I'm not just announcing, I'm "warning" someone but in a positive way. Or If I say "did you know that you must wear your seatbelt" I'm also informing someone but not really announcing.  I appreciate your help in advance. :)

Comment: How would you use the word? (Please put an answer to that into your question.) Although you haven't used the single-word-request tag, have a look at [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info).

Comment: *Alert*, *notify*, *inform*, *apprise*, *tell*, .... Also, @Lawrence SE's tag system is confusing even for veteran users, so new users can't be expected to be aware that the SWR tag even exists. But editors with sufficient rep and familiarity with the tag system can fix it for them.

Comment: @DanBron Actually, I was looking at it from another angle. Since SWR wasn't used initially, it would be unfair to add the tag and simultaneously vote to close on the basis of non-compliance with SWR. I was giving the OP the opportunity to edit the question in light of the information first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

> **notice**
>
> no·tice
>
> ˈnōdəs/
>
> noun
>
> 1. attention; observation.
>
> "their silence did not escape my notice"
>
> synonyms:  attention, observation, awareness, consciousness, perception ...
>
> 2. notification or warning of something, especially to allow preparations to be made.
>
> "interest rates are subject to fluctuation without notice"
>
> synonyms:  notification, warning, advance warning, announcement...
>
> verb
>
> 1. become aware of.
>
> "he noticed the youths behaving suspiciously"
>
> synonyms:  observe, perceive, note, see, discern, detect, spot, distinguish, mark, remark ...
>
> [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=Alert&oq=Alert&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i61l3&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=notice)

Synonyms for this particular usage include: [warning](https://www.google.com/search?q=images&biw=982&bih=1654&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwiA_aKMuc_LAhUEPCYKHZs_Ai0Q_AUIBigB#tbm=isch&q=warning), [beware](https://www.google.com/search?q=images&biw=982&bih=1654&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwiA_aKMuc_LAhUEPCYKHZs_Ai0Q_AUIBigB#tbm=isch&q=beware), [caution](https://www.google.com/search?q=images&biw=982&bih=1654&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwiA_aKMuc_LAhUEPCYKHZs_Ai0Q_AUIBigB#tbm=isch&q=caution)

Comment: Thank you! :) I think notice will do, I was thinking of too advanced words to come up with it. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think ***proclaim***, or ***declare*** are good words which fit what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

notified, informed, mentioned, told (them) all work. In your example: "I notified her of the sale at the ABC shop.